# Rails Activerecord Associaton foreign_key is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have two models that I am trying to associate.  I have Users that have_many jobs.  I set the associations in each model and added a foreign_id to the job model.  When a user fills out the form to post a job the user_id returns nil.  What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add anything to my create action? Should there be an added field in my form for the foreign_key?  Here's what I have so far.  Thanks.

```
create_table "jobs", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "location"
    t.integer  "needed"
    t.decimal  "pay"
    t.string   "how"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.decimal  "hours"
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end


create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :category, :description, :how, :location, :needed, :pay, :start_date, :title,:hours
   validates :category, :title, :description, :how, :location, :needed,:hours, :pay,:start_date, presence: true
   validates :pay, :numericality => { :greater_than => 7.99 } 
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is a schema or model issue; most likely has to do with the form.

Comment: can you post your controller code and the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, In your `create` action of `JobsController` you have to write something like:

```
current_user.jobs.build(params[:job])
```

or

```
@user.jobs.build(params[:job])
```

instead of

```
Job.new(params[:job])
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. In my create action I added @job = current_user.jobs.build(params[:job])